# Are the phrases "both in water and land" and "for the loss and damage to" grammatical?

Tags: syntax, grammar

A.   Consider the phrase that is boldfaced in sentence (1):

(1)  "It can live **both in water and land**."

Is the phrase grammatical as it is, with no preposition before "land"?   Or should the phrase be "both in water and on land"?

B.  Now consider the phrase that is boldfaced in sentence (2):

(2)  "He is responsible **for the loss and damage to** the article."

In the phrase grammatical as it is, with no preposition after "loss"?   Or should the phrase be "loss of and damage to"?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you asking about [coordinate sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordination_%28linguistics%29#Forward_vs._backward_sharing), or are you interested in the omission of one of the prepositions? The answers and comments to your [question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/20886/revolutions-can-and-often-have-begun-with-reading-why-begun-why-not-begi) already pointed to [proximity agreement](http://grammar.about.com/od/pq/g/proximityagreement.htm). It would help if you could produce a clear question.

Comment: @Man_from_India Of the five "questions" you have asked, this is the third time that I noticed that you have not actually asked a question. This justifies   other users flagging your questions closed. Please re-write your posts and ask specific questions. A bunch of closed questions helps no one.

Comment: @ThomasGross In the two sentences I quoted, is it also the case of proximity agreement or is it wrong to write those sentences that way? I have also written the how to correct the quoted sentences if quoted sentences are wrong.

Comment: @Man_From_India After second thought, the "in water and land" sounds broken to me, but that might be a result of my Spanish where we're always taught to repeat prepositions even if they are the same, such as `Vi al cartero y también al otro hombre`. - `I saw the postman and the other man`. I'd be interested in hearing what other people have to say.

Comment: It's nice that the question is clearer. However, questions of grammaticality are off-topic here.